# Why is eurodollar future so popular

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, finance

It's well-know that eurodollar futures contracts are the most liquid contracts in the world. Traders use them to express views on interest rates or hedge interest rate risks.

My questions is why are they so popular? Why are treasury futures not as popular as Eurodollar contracts, for example?

Comment: Eurodollar futures were discontinued on April 13, 2023...